# R eurostat selecting date

Tags: r, dplyr

I am downloading data from eurostat using the package "eurostat". My idea is to build a bar plot, comparing how the minimum wage to average wage ratio has changed in 2008 vs 2016. 
But the problem I am encountering is by selecting the time (time %in% c("2008-01-01" ,"2016-01-01")). This line retrieves an empty tibble. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot

reproducible example"

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat)

#retrieving data
earn_mw_avgr2 <- get_eurostat("earn_mw_avgr2", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#buidling bar plot
ggplot(data=earn_mw_avgr2 %>%filter(nace_r2=="B-S",
                                    geo %in% c("EU", "BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR","IT","CY","LV","LT","LU","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO","SI","SK","FI","SE","UK"),
                                    indic_se=="MW_MEAGE",
                                    time %in% c("2008-01-01" ,"2016-01-01")),
       aes(x=reorder(geo, values), y=values, fill=time))+
        geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                 position = "dodge",
                 show.legend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to compare 2008 vs 2016, this should help

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(data=earn_mw_avgr2 %>% 
     #mutate(year = year(time)) %>%  #No need to create a new column, implement lubridate::year function directly on time column
     filter(nace_r2=="B-S",
                                geo %in% c("EU", "BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR","IT","CY","LV","LT","LU","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO","SI","SK","FI","SE","UK"),
                                indic_se=="MW_MEAGE",
                                year(time) %in% c("2008" ,"2016")),
      aes(x=reorder(geo, values), y=values, fill=time))+
   geom_bar(stat = "identity",
       position = "dodge",
       show.legend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    library(lubridate)

    filter(year(time) %in% c(year("2008-01-01"), year("2016-01-01")))
```